# Getting logicals from a simple for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, na

I am kind of new to working with loops so please be kind.

So I have these lines of code:

```
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,2]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,3]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,4]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,5]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,6]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,7]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,8]))
isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,9]))
```

I am just checking if there are any NA's in my dataframe.

My output:

```
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,2]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,3]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,4]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,5]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,6]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,7]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,8]))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,9]))
[1] FALSE
```

Why is this not working:

```
for (i in 2:9) {
 isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,i]))
}

print(i)
```

Output:

```
> for (i in 2:9) {
+      isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,i]))
+    }
> print(i)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way OP is trying to check if there are any `NA`s in his data is not recommended.

Example data

```
(dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, NA, NA, 2),
                   col2 = 3))
#  col1 col2
#1    1    3
#2   NA    3
#3   NA    3
#4    2    3
```

OP's method using `isTRUE`

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  print(isTRUE(is.na(dat[,i])))
}
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
```

You could use `anyNA` instead of `isTRUE` and maybe `sapply` instead of a for loop but that is up to you

```
sapply(dat, anyNA)
# col1  col2 
# TRUE FALSE
```

Thanks to @Gregor!

If you need the number of `NA`s for each column you can try

```
sapply(dat, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# col1 col2
#    2    0
```

or more efficiently

```
colSums(is.na(dat))
#col1 col2 
#   2    0
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to print within the loop

```
print(isTRUE(is.na(METEO_Data[,i])))
```

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the number of iteration when you print `i`.
If you want to check for `NA` fo all your dataframe, just use `is.na(df)`.